# Reshaping Multiple Matrices in a List

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a large list of the form:

```
{{0.25 + 0. I, 0.353553 + 1.15304*10^-16 I, 0.25 - 1.38778*10^-17 I, 
  0.353553 - 1.15304*10^-16 I, 0.5 + 0. I, 0.353553 - 1.3493*10^-16 I,
   0.25 + 1.38778*10^-17 I, 0.353553 + 1.3493*10^-16 I, 
  0.25 + 0. I}}
```

This is just the first entry in the list. By default it is a $9 \times 1$ array/matrix.

How do I use a combination of `MapThread` and `ArrayReshape` to convert each array in the list (denoted by a sublist) into a $3 \times 3$ array?

`MapThread[ArrayReshape , {listname, {3, 3}}]` doesn't work. Any suggestions?

---

Edit:

On the list given above when I apply

```
ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}] & /@ listname
```

I get:

[image]

How do I correctly make a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Comment: So `listname` dimensions are `{n, 1, 9}`?

Comment: And why do you insist on `MapThread and ArrayReshap`?

Comment: This is a job for `Map`, not `MapThread`.  Just map `ArrayReshape[#, {3,3}]&`.

Comment: @Szabolcs See the edit.

Comment: @Kuba See the edit.

Comment: `Flatten[ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}] & /@ listname, 1] // MatrixForm`

Comment: What is your point?  That is a list containing a single 3x3 matrix.  I think the question isn't phrased very accurately.  Give a *short and simple* example: this is my input, this is the output I want.

Comment: A saw the edit and there's no answer to my first comment.

Comment: I gave the answer to this question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125330/3066)